# Draw a line thinner than a pixel in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Is it possible to draw a line on an image which has a thickness smaller than the size of the image pixel, like the image below? My code below only allows me to draw a line of 1 pixel thick.

```
Mat image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
line(image,cvPoint(0,0),cvPoint(10,10),CV_RGB(255,255,255),1,8); // Thickness = 1 (1 pixel thick)
namedWindow("Display Window", WINDOW_NORMAL );
imshow( "Display Window", image);
```

[image]

[Edited] Solution:

```
Mat image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat image_zoom = Mat(image.size()*10, CV_32F);   // zoom in 10 times
resize(image, image_zoom, image_zoom.size(), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);
line(draw,cvPoint(0,0),cvPoint(100,100),CV_RGB(255,255,255),1,8);
namedWindow("Display Window", WINDOW_NORMAL );
imshow( "Display Window", image_zoom);
```

Comment: no, not possible. how should that ever work ?

Comment: is there any other alternative? like drawing the line on another layer on top of the zoomed-in image?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? some mixed pixel information, so a semi-transparent line is drawn?
To get that you can draw the line on a separate image, then add both images weighted (alpha-blending) but just for all the pixels that are not black (or any other alpha color) in the line layer.

Comment: or an antialiased line so that the sharp edges aren't so present from one line pixel to the next one?

Comment: I want to add gradient orientation on the pixel. Like quiver() in matlab.

Comment: I mean what do you expect a line thinner than 1 pixel to look like, or why does it have to be thinner than 1 pixel (what's impossible since nothing smaller than a pixel can be displayed on your screen, so everything that "fakes" to be thinner than a pixel is whether transparent or antialiased or something else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try anti-aliased lines instead of 8-connected lines:

`line(grad,cvPoint(0,0),cvPoint(10,10),CV_RGB(255,255,255),1,CV_AA); // anti-aliased`

if that's not ok yet you can try to draw your line in a zoomed view (possibly with arrowheads) and resize that image.
Try `cv::resize()` with the `INTER_AREA` parameter to downsample a zoomed drawing.

Comment: It works! I've updated my question with the solution.